# duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SBJSON when using CloudMade and Facebook iOs SDKs

Tags: facebook, ios, cloudmade

I'm trying to compile a project that uses both CloudMade and Facebook.
The Facebook SDK also includes the SBJson library so I get a link error:

duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SBJSON in ../CloudMadeApi/libs/CloudMade/libCloudMadeApi.a(SBJSON.o) and (...)/Objects-normal/i386/SBJSON.o

If I exclude the Facebook SBJson .m files from the build it compiles but then the SBJson methods are not found at run time.

I'm using the latest CloudMade and Facebook SDKs.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Is cloudmade shipped as a binary library or do you have the source?

Comment: Hello, this issue will be fixed soon by removing SBJSON from CloudMade iPhone and iPad SDK.

Answer (score 1):

this issue will be fixed soon by removing SBJSON from CloudMade iPhone and iPad SDK. Here is forum post about it: http://support.cloudmade.com/forums/iphone-sdk/posts/1399/show